# How to automate the DDMS snapshot mechanism?

Tags: android, android-ndk, ddms, android-testing

Does [Android DDMS](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/ddms.html) provide APIs ? I need to automate the snapshot mechanism for the native heap. Or is there any post processing tool for analysis DDMS native heap snapshots.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I assume by snapshot you mean a heap dump.

From your app code you can call [`Debug.dumpHprofData()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Debug.html#dumpHprofData%28java.lang.String%29) to dump the data.

From a script you can call

```
adb shell am dumpheap <process> <file>
```

where `<process>` is e.g. your process id or name, and `<file>` is the dump file name. After that you can `adb pull` the dump to your computer.

To analyze the heap dumps you can use e.g. jhat or MAT. Before that you need to run `hprof-conv` (included in Android SDK) on the dump to convert it from Dalvik format to standard Java format.

Further reading: [Memory Analysis for Android Applications](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/memory-analysis-for-android.html)

Comment: how do I use MAT from the command line? I found a solution to use ParseHeapDump.sh, but how to use that?

Answer (score 8):

@laalto's answer is not quite correct

From a shell you can do the following to get a heap dump for the application using adb.

**Note:** Replace **19000** with the process ID of your running application. The filepath must be a filepath which your application has **write access** to on the Android device.

Create a heap dump:
`adb shell am dumpheap 19000 /sdcard/Documents/android.hprof`
Pull the file to your machine:
`adb pull /sdcard/Documents/android.hprof`
Convert to a hprof file readable by an analyzer:
`hprof-conv android.hprof mat.hprof`

Tips:
Get process ID of your application:

`adb shell ps | grep com.sample.application | cut -c10-15`

Get process ID and dump heap:

`` adb shell am dumpheap `adb shell ps | grep com.sample.application | cut -c10-15` /sdcard/Documents/android.hprof ``

Answer (score 0):

The DDMS provides a UI for the ADB. You can use ADB commands directly and process the output. The ADB documentation can be found here:
http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html

Answer (score 0):

I wrote small script, maybe you would find it useful

```
heap_dump_location='/data/local/tmp/tmp.hprof'

dump_heap() {
  adb shell rm $heap_dump_location
  pid=`adb shell ps | grep 'com.example.packagename' | grep -v 'packagename\.' | cut -c10-15`
  adb shell am dumpheap $pid $heap_dump_location
  echo "Heap dump started, we have no idea when it's done, so take a look at logs, and when is done use pull_heap_dump"
}

pull_heap_dump() {
  adb pull $heap_dump_location $1
}
```

https://gist.github.com/logcat/8aeca0ee81af6fb0dc10bb0d58940007